# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() using Batch File

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP that downloads files from backend. I am using WAMP in Windows 7 and it works perfectly when done through the browser.

Now I have created a batch file to execute the php and it shows:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Not sure why something that could work over in browser is not working in batch file. Below is my code for the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\test\test.php"
```

Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Check the php.ini for your cli environment.

Comment: install php curl library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uncomment the following on your php.ini

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

and restart webserver. This might be due to curl disabled in your php.

Answer (score 2):

When you use wamp, xamp or other all-in-one server, it uses an overrided php.ini located into bin/conf/ instead where original is.

You need copy from these or edit the ini located at php.exe folder.

If you cant access it (shared server, etc), you can create a custom php.ini file into script folder, and put needed instructions:

```
extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/" // change version if needed to yours
extension = php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

When using through browser it is using WAMP and the  PHP ini is from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

But I have set my php directory to C:\php-5.4.9 in environmental variables, thus when using windows batch it is calling php from that directory and there was no php.ini file there.

I copied the PHP ini file from wamp to php folder and now it is working.

Apparently I have installed php and then wamp, thus there is a overlap which has caused confusion.

Comment: What about the -c param? You can put the ini file anywhere. Watch at http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that my environment was not complete... then i just install php5-curl:

1. `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`
2. restart server